# Parsing and selecting from HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Using an ajax call I have returned the partialView HTML of a page, but before I display it I wish to pull information from the main div. This data is just size information, for if I create a floating window.

Code:

```
<div class="window-details" data-height="500px" data-width="500px">more data here</div>

this.PopUp = function (url, title) {
  $.ajax(url)
  .success(function (partialViewHtml) {
     var partialViewDom = $(partialViewHtml);
     var thisDiv = $(".window-details", partialViewDom);
```

I can see the data in chromes debugger when hovering over partialViewDom, but the class selection does not appear to have worked. Any clues? Does it not parse correctly? Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `partialViewHtml`? If it's `'<div class="window-details" data-height="500px" data-width="500px">more data here</div>'`, then there is no child of that HTML with class `window-details`, which is what you're trying to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `.filter()` instead, most likely your `.window-details` element is a top level element in the dom fragment.

```
var thisDiv = partialViewDom.filter(".window-details");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code searches for elements with the `.window-details` in the *children* of the div that was returned.