# Having trouble parsing html using jQuery $.get()

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing and selecting from HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354105/parsing-and-selecting-from-html-string)

So, I have the following jQuery get function:

```
$.get('newwindow.html', function(data){
  h = data;
})
```

My goal is to do something with h. Basically it's returning a bunch of html, but I want a specific div out of it. I've tried:

```
$(h).find('#div_name')
```

I've also tried altering the inside of my callback to:

```
h = $('#div_name', data);
```

or

```
h = $('#div_name', $(data));
```

to no avail, the best solution i've succeeded with so far is putting the following in my callback:

```
$(data).each(function(k,v){
  if ( $(v).attr('id') === 'div_name') h = $(v).text();
});
```

This seems terribly inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: You might be looking for `.filter`: http://api.jquery.com/filter/, if `#div_name` is a "top level" element in your HTML (which seems to be the case considering your `.each` loop).

Answer (score 0):

To parse the `html` from your ajax call use `jQuery .filter()`

**Example usage:**

```
$(function () {
    $.get('newwindow.html', function (data) {
        var h = data;
        console.log($(h).filter('#div_name').html());
        //alert($(h).filter('#div_name').html()); //Use this alert if using IE
    });
});
```

For more information on jQuery .filter() visit: http://api.jquery.com/filter/